# C++ Threading with Boost Library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want my function running in a separate thread. I use Boost library and include like this in my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
```

I want the thread start like this:

```
boost::thread ethread(Engine::function,info);
// info is an object from the class Engine and i need this in the
// function
```

My `Engine` class is in the `func.h` and the function looks like this:

```
void Engine::function(Engine info)
{
    //STUFF
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
}
```

BTW: Is the `sleep` function for the thread right?

Every time I want to compile it gives me this error:

```
error C3867: "Engine::function": function call missing argument list; use '&Engine::function' to create a pointer to member
```

I tried to use `&Engine::function` in the thread and this error appears:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

I also tried:

```
boost::thread ethread(Engine::function,info, _1);
```

Then this error appeared:

```
error C2784: "result_traits<R,F>::type boost::_bi::list0::operator [](const boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L> &) const"
```

Can someone help me with this? I only want to run the function beside the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use bind function to create functional object with pointer to class member function or make your function static.

http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

More detailed explanation:
boost::thread constructor needs pointer to a function. In case of normal functions syntax is simple: `&hello`

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world, I'm a thread!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread thrd(&hello);
    thrd.join();
    return 0;
}
```

But if you need pointer to a function of class you have to remember that such functions have implicit parameter - `this` pointer, so you have to pass it also. You can do this by creating callable object with std::bind, or boost bind.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Foo{
public:
    void print( int a )
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    boost::thread t( std::bind( &Foo::print, &foo, 5 ) );
    t.join();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what I have to do know?

Comment: @NicMaxFen see update for more details. From your code it's hard to say what exactly you should do, please post more code

Comment: there is no more code related to this. Now i get this error:
 fatal error LNK1104: File"libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_60.lib" could not be opend.

My Line of code i changed:

boost::thread(boost::bind(&Engine::function,&info, info));

Comment: @NicMaxFen you are calling method of info object and passing it as a parameter! You definetly do it smth weird. It's a typical linker error" linker could not find boost library. Some boost components not just headers, they implicity link libraries using auto-linking